# What is this icon on top of the photo on the share sheet?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, sharing

When on the share sheet trying to share a photo, I noticed this icon:

[image]

What does this icon mean?

Device:

- iPhone SE (1st Generation) running iOS 13.4.1

Comment: Does this show up on other screens?  Maybe your home screen?

Comment: was the photo panoramic

Comment: @ankii no It wasn’t

Comment: @jmh nope it doesn’t